# Метод Extend для примесей.Не понятен фрагмент с "примешиванием" замыканий вызывающие методы примесей

Tags: javascript, объекты, замыкания, mixins

Не пойму кусок кода из статьи  про примеси(mixin),там где "примешивают" замыкания. Конкретно  в  строках 1 и 2 не понятно что происходит?Ссылка на статью https://habr.com/post/132340/

```js
function extend_2(object)
{
    var mixins = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < mixins.length; ++i)
    {
        for (var prop in mixins[i])
        {
            if (typeof object.prototype[prop] === "undefined")
            {
                bindMethod = function (mixin, prop) //(1)
                {
                    return function () { mixin[prop].apply(this, arguments) }
                }

                object.prototype[prop] = bindMethod(mixins[i], prop);//(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря, в этих строках происходит хрень. Одно из двух: или это был пример как не надо делать - или автор статьи сам не знает что делает.

Comment: _Конкретно в строках 1 и 2_ - в первой строке объявляется функция, во второй - выполняется. Стоит добавить ссылку на статью.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/132340/

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, 11 год, довольно много времени прошло

Comment: ну,на js лёрне,к сожалению комментарии к урокам, имеющие максимальное количество оценок дают ссылки на статьи 5ти летней (и более) давности

Comment: Не ходи на этот сайт :-) В любом случае добавил ответ. Так же в самой статье указано, для чего это делается и после чего было добавлено. Исходный комментарий: https://habr.com/post/132340/#comment_4394219

Comment: Есть русскоязычные  ресурсы поинтереснее js  лёрна?)

Comment: ru SO :-D ну или mdn хотя б :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В указанных строках

```
bindMethod = function (mixin, prop) //(1)
{
    return function () { mixin[prop].apply(this, arguments) }
}

object.prototype[prop] = bindMethod(mixins[i], prop);//(2)
```

Происходит следующее:

1. создается функция, которая

   1. принимает два параметра
   2. возвращает новую функцию
   3. в возвращаемой функции вызывается метод, которому устанавливается текущий `this` и `arguments`.
2. вызывается созданная функция, и результат записывается в переменную.

---

Если не обращать внимания, что `bindMethod` утекает в глобальную область видимости, можно сказать, что эта функция вообще не нужна, так как кроме создания *еще одной* функции ничего не делает.

Поэтому указанный код можно заменить на следующий:

```
object.prototype[prop] = mixins[i][prop];
```

---

Если прочитать [исходную статью](https://habr.com/post/132340/) можно отметить, что данная функция была введена для того, чтобы была возможность подменить саму функцию `mixin`, после того, как она уже была куда-то примешена.

Пример:

```js
function extend_2(construct, ...mixins) {
  mixins.forEach(mixin => {
    for (var prop in mixin) {
      if (typeof construct.prototype[prop] === "undefined") {
        var bindMethod = function(mixin, prop) //(1)
        {
          return function() {
            mixin[prop].apply(this, arguments)
          }
        }

        construct.prototype[prop] = bindMethod(mixin, prop); //(2)
      }
    }

  });
}

var mixins = {
  say: function() {
    console.log('base say')
  }
}

function A() {}

extend_2(A, mixins);

var a = new A();

a.say();

mixins.say = function() {
  console.log('new say')
}

a.say();
```